# looking for Android dialog widget with rounded corners

Tags: android, dialog

I'm looking for an Android dialog component like this screenshot:

[image: large dialog box with title and close button]

Apologies for the white dialog on a white background but hopefully you can see the nice elevation shadow, the rounded corners, and importantly the close button on the top right of the dialog.
(The screenshot is taken from a tab-less version of the Chrome app).

Does anyone know of a library/snippet that achieves this, or something like it? Thanks.

**edit:**
Some background info which hopefully will make the question clearer: I have a scrolling activity which has a lot of content - text and data - in which I would like to show further details/images via clickable text/image. Yes I could use an AlertDialog but I much prefer the look of the dialog window in the screenshot.

Comment: Use a `CardView` for the background of your dialog for the rounded corners and elevation. Use an `ImageView` with a clickable background for the close button.

Comment: use can you `CardView` as layout wrapper in XML file to get shadow.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I hadn't realized that CardView was so flexible, that's a good suggestion. I have seen in the docs that using the Theme.Holo.Dialog will display an activity as a dialog. I shall try this.

Comment: @Ta Quang Tu: Thanks, I'll try it as a wrapper around a DialogFragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution (one month later). @Bunny suggests making the background of the dialog fragment **transparent**.
Specificially, in the onCreateView of the DialogFragment class, add:

```
dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

This works, but with the restriction that it has to be a '*drawable*' background. But first of all, the result - a dialog with rounded corners:

[image: screenshot of a dialog with rounded corners]

Okay, the code is as follows. Here is my '**rounded_corners.xml**' shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="16dp"
        android:left="16dp"
        android:right="16dp"
        android:top="16dp" />
</shape>
```

Which is used in the dialog fragment layout, **dialog_bigly.xml**, within the base CardView widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/base_card"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="500dp"
  android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
  app:cardElevation="10dp" >

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDialog_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
        android:text="Dialog Title here"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnDialog_close"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnDialog_close"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnDialog_close"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_red_close_24x24" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivDialog_Image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtDialog_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_image185x285" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And lastly here is the **DialogBig.kt** kotlin code:

```
package ...

import ...

class DialogBig: DialogFragment() {
  override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity!!)
    val inflater = activity!!.layoutInflater
    val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_bigly, null)

    val txtTitle = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtDialog_title)
    val imgImage = dialogView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivDialog_Image)
    val btnClose = dialogView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.btnDialog_close)

    builder.setView(dialogView)
    btnClose.setOnClickListener { dismiss() }
    txtTitle.text = "my bigly dialog test title"
    return builder.create()
  }

  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
  }
}
```

Although I don't really understand how this works, I'm glad to have found a solution. I think part of the issue is trying to get access to the fragment holder container in the depths of the DialogFragment class to apply the transparency, rather than simply the fragment layout itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:background="#B4CCCCCC"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; but this seems to be a permanent display; I am looking for a dialog object which can be called by existing layout, show the dialog, and then when closed the user is back at the original layout.  I will edit my question to make it clearer. Also, I see a warning from Android Studio with this code:
This RelativeLayout view is useless (no children, no background, no id, no style)

Answer (score 0):

Well, following the suggestion above, this is the result of a rough test of a basic activity, containing a CardView, with the Theme.Holo.Dialog theme:

[image: an activity acting as a dialog form]

And using a CardView does show the rounded corners and elevation nicely, as required, but there is a big problem - the original layout (the one from where the dailog is called) isn't seen underneath and below the dialog, this area of the screen is blank. So it's not acting like a dialog. A custom dialog, based on DialogFragment, is the only way forward, and that is my next objective.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I've failed. This is the best I can come up with:

[image: screenshot of dialog]

The dialog is now acting like a dialog, placed above the user screen, and the CardView widget, as suggested above, is fine, but the DialogFragment places it within a white rectangular window.  Not what I wanted.  In case someone else feels the urge to take up the challenge, here is my layout xml, the dialog class and the code snippet that calls it:

**dialog_bigly.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="550dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6">
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                    android:text="  Dialog Title here"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtDialog_title"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_do_not_disturb"
                    android:id="@+id/btnDialog_close" android:layout_gravity="right" android:clickable="true"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_image207x344"
                    android:id="@+id/ivDialog_Image"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**DialogBig.kt**

```
package ...
import ...

class DialogBig: DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity!!)
        val inflater = activity!!.layoutInflater
        val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_bigly, null)

        val txtTitle = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtDialog_title)
        val imgImage = dialogView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivDialog_Image)
        val btnClose = dialogView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.btnDialog_close)

        builder.setView(dialogView)
        btnClose.setOnClickListener { dismiss() }
        txtTitle.text = "dialog bigly title"

        return builder.create()
    }
}
```

and finally **code snippet**

```
btn_test.setOnClickListener {
    //create a new bigly dialog
    val dialog = DialogBig()
    dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "testing")
}
```